# Convert Visual C++ Console Application to Linux Application

Tags: c++, linux, console

is there an easy way to convert a VC++ Win32 Console Project to a Linux Terminal Application?
The Project isn't very complex and does not use specific Windows Libs. I am looking for a Tool or something that creates e.g. a Makefile. VS Version is 2013.

Comment: If it doesn't use ANY windows dependant libs then you should be able to just copy the source and compile with the g++ compiler.

Comment: Or if you wan't a tool to **generate** a makefile, take a look at [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)

Comment: Well the obvious ways is the one i didn't saw... There were some few changes necessary to compile with g++ but now it runs. Thanks for the help :D